# WebBrowser control scaling on hidpi displays

Tags: vsto, office-addins

We're currently building an add-in to host an some html content as a VSTO add-in for Outlook.  However, on a hidpi display the scaling factor for the WebBrowser control is incorrect.  Instead of scaling based on the scaled displayed percentage (250% on a 4k 15in display) it's leaving the scaling at 100%.  I've verified this by querying `window.devicePixelRatio` which is just returning 1.0.

I've tried using an answer described here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/151dcd48-4f09-4701-aa10-edc34617e7f2/how-to-zoom-a-web-browser-programatically-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral which applies zoom on the WebBrowser control itself however only text elements appear to zoom.

I've also tried applying a zoom style on the HTML document itself from the WebBrowser control `webBrowser.Document.Body.Style = "zoom: 150%;"`

When hosting the same code in a standalone WinForms application, `window.devicePixelRatio` is the expected value of `2.50` and everything just works.

Are there any known workarounds other than those described above?

Comment: Might be related to [VSTO custom taskpane on multi DPI system shows content twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100564/vsto-custom-taskpane-on-multi-dpi-system-shows-content-twice)

Comment: Just wondering, is there any reason you are not using web add-ins with Office.js? If you're hosting a web page, it seems like you're almost there.

Comment: To clarify, I believe dynamic DPI is supported in web add-ins.

Comment: Some text elements weren't scaling correctly since there was no explicit `font-size` specified.  I'm not sure what values they were inheriting or where they were coming from.  Once applied, zoom on the WebBrowser control worked fine.

Comment: We have customers with older Exchange deployments, I'm using the same codebase as our web add-ins though :)